# Firebase working without permission.INTERNET... How?

Tags: android, firebase

My firebase application is running perfectly on my android device without having added the permission.INTERNET flag. I installed Firebase directly from gradle. I am aware that adding Firebase through the project structure window in android studio will add the permissions.INTERNET for you. But this is not the case, my Android manifest has nothing in regards to permission.INTERNET yet is still fully functional...

I havent been able to find any info on this... Is this because its now run by Google?

Comment: The permission is probably coming from the library itself: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html

Comment: Which module of Firebase are you using?

Comment: *firebaser here* @CommonsWare the permission is indeed is merged in from the AAR. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [documentation for manifest merging](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) states:

> During the build process, the manifest merge process stores a record
>   of each merge transaction in the
>   manifest-merger-{productFlavor}-report.txt file in the module
>   build/outputs/logs folder. A different log file is generated for each
>   of the module's build variants.

You can look there for a detailed explanation of which library is providing the permission.

Or since you are using Android Studio, you can use Ctrl-Shift-N and type "AndroidManifest.xml" to see a dropdown menu of all the manifests in your build and open them to see what they contain.

A feature was added to Android Studio 2.2 to show the results of manifest merging.  When viewing the manifest in an Editor window, select the Merged Manifest tab at the bottom of the window to see the contributors to the manifest.

In my build, which includes a number of Firebase libraries, the manifest that adds the INTERNET permission appears to be:

```
com.google.firebase\firebase-analytics\9.4.0\AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: Ah terrific, thank you for the answer and resource! My Internet permission also seems to come from the analytics library! I wasn't much informed on manifest merging, great to learn something new!

Comment: The permission for INTERNET is included by the manifest of `firebase-firestore:17.1.2`.

Answer (score 1):

I was manually managing my Mobile Data's permissions and I discover that, if I block mobile data on "Google Backup Transport", I cannot connect to Firebase.
I really think this is the reason You can use Your app even without INTERNET permissions.