# Why Firebase can work on my app without INTERNET permission

Tags: android, security, firebase

I recently implemented a basic app using Firebase, follow tutorials, do some things, I deployed my app to other people, then I just read the manifest and I figure out I don't have any permissions on it. How is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/39058037/4815718

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, the permission is there. The permission is added automatically when you add the Firebase SDK.

If you are using Android Studio 2.2, you can view the merged manifest to see which library is adding that permission by opening the `AndroidManifest.xml` and then tap on the `Merged Manifest` tab below.