# Firebase ads: java.lang.InstantiationError: com.google.android.gms.internal.zznv

Tags: android, firebase, admob

Adding AdMob to my Android app drives me mad :o

Firebase is already running (auth, db, ...).

I added gradle dependency for ads too.
I followed Google instructions exactly.
I have two issues:

1. The AdView Container in my xml layout file cannot be rendered in the preview. It says:

> The following classes could not be instantiated: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
>
> Exception Details java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeh   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzez.  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzez.  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzez.  at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.  at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)

2. If I try to initialize ads in my code, it crashes in this code-line:

> MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
>
> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.InstantiationError: com.google.android.gms.internal.zznv
>                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeh.(Unknown Source)
>                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeh.(Unknown Source)
>                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfb.zza(Unknown Source)
>                            at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(Unknown Source)
>                            at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(Unknown Source)
>                            at de.philweb.myweightlog.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:233)

I tried everything I found on SO. Like MultiDex and adding AdsActivity to manifest, no success. Now I really need your help :(

Thanks guys,
phil

the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.philweb.myweightlog">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.philweb.myweightlog"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
//        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
//    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1' //22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1' //22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
//    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.0'

    compile "com.androidplot:androidplot-core:1.4.0"
    compile 'com.darwinsys:hirondelle-date4j:1.5.1'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Post your app build.gradle file.

Comment: Are you seeing this issue in both debug and release versions?  If by chance it's only for release build, and you're using ProGuard, then issue might be that you need to add `keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }` to your ProGuard config file.

Comment: i added the build.gradle....... i have the issues in debug mode...i didnt export as release buil and dont use proguard AFAIK :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size and number of included libraries requires Multidex.  You say you tried to enable it.  Note that [three steps are required](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle), including a change to the manifest.

Also, when using version 10.0.1 of the Firebase libs, you must use version 1.0.1 of Firebase UI:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
```

The [Firebase UI docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) contains a table of compatible versions.

Comment: thankx man!! upgrading firebase-ui helped already! now admob works. i will try multidex, too but it seems that i wouldnt have to

Comment: hm...MultiDex doesnt work...but the app works now with admob.....E/UncaughtException: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:552)

Comment: The `StackOverflowError` is not relate to MultiDex.  If you try to run your app on a pre-Lollipop device, I'm confident you will see errors related to more that 65K method references.  I built a test app with your dependencies, tried to run it on an API 19 device, and saw the errors.

Comment: ok thanks...thats good to know. then i will have to try multidex again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

put this in menifest.

Comment: thankx, but doesnt change anything.... (besides that: why can i sync my data with firebase-cloud-DB when there is no permission Internet????!)

Comment: for admob see this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

Comment: And about the data you are synching are may be shared internally. because it is not possible to access data on the internet, when you don't have permission to access the internet.

Comment: @Simo: The permission is merged from Firebase libs.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39058748/4815718

Comment: well, as the post says the permission is merged so the app is accessing data. I had similar problem which was solved by just adding the permission. anyway keep digging.